# Assign a global Array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, global-variables

I found a project to learn Python: Tetris
My plan was to assign a global Array in a variable() function to clean up my main() function.

but i get a syntax error

```
def globalv():
    global x
    x = 40
    global y
    y = 10
    global Tetris[40][10]
    for x in 40:
        for y in 10:
            Tetris[x][y] = 0

def main():
    globalv()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong
Thank you

Comment: `Tetris[40][10]` is not a valid variable name. Did you mean `global Tetris`? Does not achieve anything useful, certainly not making the code clean, but it does not syntax error ...

Comment: now i got 2 syntax errors instead of 1
I think global is just needed when you are assigning the variable

Comment: Please provided a stack trace of error when you are asking such questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in the `for` loops as well as the use of `global Tetris[40][10]`.

The error on `global` is simply that you have added the index, you only make global the variable itself. So:

`global Tetris`

If you are more familiar with C or Java, the fact that you need to declare variables and their sizes is not a thing in python (at the most basic levels).

The error you are getting on the `for` loops should be something along the lines of: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

The `for` keyword requires an iterator, this is essentially something you go through in steps, like a list. Integers are not iterable, the "literal" english of saying "for number in 40" makes sense but it does not in code.

What you need is to use the `range` keyword which will generate essentially a list of numbers up to, *but not including*, the number. So you should use:

`for x in range(40):`